# Xpath expression to retrieve all child node's value only

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I need an XPath expression to retrieve only **specific** values of *BalanceResult* attribute from following sample XML script:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ars:QueryBalanceResultMsg xmlns:ars="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/arservices" xmlns:arc="http://cbs.huawei.com/ar/wsservice/arcommon" xmlns:cbs="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbscommon">
        <QueryBalanceResult>
            <ars:AcctList>
                <ars:BalanceResult>
                    <arc:BalanceType>C_MAIN_ACCOUNT</arc:BalanceType>
                    <arc:BalanceTypeName>MainAccount</arc:BalanceTypeName>
                    <arc:TotalAmount>80000</arc:TotalAmount>
                    <arc:BalanceDetail>
                        <arc:BalanceInstanceID>702000000000008916</arc:BalanceInstanceID>
                        <arc:EffectiveTime>20160803080942</arc:EffectiveTime>
                        <arc:ExpireTime>20370101010000</arc:ExpireTime>
                    </arc:BalanceDetail>
                </ars:BalanceResult>
                <ars:BalanceResult>
                    <arc:BalanceType>C_Bonus_Account</arc:BalanceType>
                    <arc:BalanceTypeName>Bonus Balance Account</arc:BalanceTypeName>
                    <arc:TotalAmount>3900</arc:TotalAmount>
                    <arc:BalanceDetail>
                        <arc:BalanceInstanceID>702000000000008543</arc:BalanceInstanceID>
                        <arc:EffectiveTime>20160803082506</arc:EffectiveTime>
                        <arc:ExpireTime>20191211121212</arc:ExpireTime>
                    </arc:BalanceDetail>
                </ars:BalanceResult>
               .......
            </ars:AcctList>
        </QueryBalanceResult>
    </ars:QueryBalanceResultMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Such that my expression returns something like this:

C_MAIN_ACCOUNT, 80000, 20370101010000, C_Bonus_Account, 3900, 20191211121212,...
*template for above:(arc:BalanceType, arc:TotalAmount, arc:ExpireTime)*

Below expression returns everything including the tags-not needed.

```
//*[local-name()='BalanceResult'][*[local-name()='BalanceType']]
```

Also since there might be n number of **BalanceResult** attributes(in sample above, its 2), i'm not able to come up with a solution.

Appreciate any help!Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
//BalanceResult/descendant::*[local-name() = 'BalanceType' or local-name() = 'TotalAmount' or local-name() = 'ExpireTime']
```

This results in:

```
<BalanceType>C_MAIN_ACCOUNT</BalanceType>
<TotalAmount>80000</TotalAmount>
<ExpireTime>20370101010000</ExpireTime>
<BalanceType>C_Bonus_Account</BalanceType>
<TotalAmount>3900</TotalAmount>
<ExpireTime>20191211121212</ExpireTime>
```

Note that I removed the namespaces from your example.